# Aging bucket in SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which has member ID along with LM_Conversion_date and retired_date. I have managed to get the difference between two date but now i would like to have the aging bucket and reflect those membership number which falls under those bucket. Here is my table example and how i want to see the data,

```
Member_no   LM_Conversion_date  Retired_date    Date_difference
100026            08/12/2017    31/12/2017      23
100114            31/08/2017    31/08/2017      0
100620            15/09/2017    30/09/2017      15
100726             10/01/2017   31/12/2016     -10
```

I want the output to be

```
All negative      0-15      15-30     >30
100726            100114    100026   
                  100620
```

Any Help will be much appreciated

Comment: This isn't the sort of thing that SQL Server is good at; it might be better handled in your presentation layer.  Also, the `0` I see under the `<30` category might be misplaced, assuming you don't want a number there which could be misinterpreted as a member number.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes its a member's ID, i have made the correction. Can we do a aging bucket with query?

Comment: Is it OK if the aging bucket is added as a 5th column inside your posted data?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when grp = '<0' then member_no end) as all_negative,
       max(case when grp = '<=15' then member_no end) as [0-15],
       max(case when grp = '<=30' then member_no end) as [15-30],
       max(case when grp = '>30' then member_no end) as [>30]      
from (select t.*, v.grp,
             row_number() over (partition by grp order by member_no) as seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (values (case when date_difference <= 0 then '<0'
                         when date_difference <= 15 then '<=15'
                         when date_difference <= 30 then '<=30'
                         else '>30'
                    end)
           ) v(grp)
      ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

The subquery basically enumerates the members in each group.  These are aggregated into separate rows by the aggregation.

Comment: sorry brother, i'm getting error Invalid column name 'grp'.